# Flashing green when cell value increases, red when decreases

Tags: excel, colors, cells, vba

I have a feed in my excel sheet and want the cell to flash green / red if the value changes up or down respectivey. Can someone help on this? Thanks.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range

   Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B27")

   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
          Is Nothing Then

       Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 36

   End If
End Sub
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: Something not mentioned below, if you don't want to have secondary columns for previous values, you can use `Application.Undo` in a `Worksheet_Change` event to get the previous value of a cell, and then `.Redo`, and compare the two. Be careful if the `Worksheet_Change` range is larger than one cell (i.e. paste actions) or caused my a macro changing the cell, in which case undo history is often disabled.

Answer (score 0):

... You can't really make it flash, but you can change the shading...

The way I would do it is, somewhere not being used in the workbook, create a set of cells that will store the cells old value (you can set these cells in the `Worksheet_Change` event), then it's just a matter of creating a conditional format rule for your cells to compare your cell's value against the helper cell's value - If larger, shading = green, if smaller, sahding = red.

Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

As John Bustos said, you need another column that houses the `previous value` of the cell. This value is necessary in order to do comparison to discern if the target is now higher or lower.

In order to achieve a flash, you need to set a pause in the code without freezing up the main UI. This code isn't tested or guaranteed to work as you want, but it should serve as a very good starting point.

**CODE**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Dim KeyCells As Range
   Set KeyCells = Range("B1:B27")

   If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
          Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value > Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value Then
            'flash green
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Pause 0.5
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Pause 0.5
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        ElseIf Target.Value < Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value Then
            'flash red
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Pause 0.5
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 2
            Pause 0.5
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
        Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value = Target.Value
   End If
End Sub

'Pauses execution without holding up main UI thread
Public Function Pause(NumberOfSeconds As Variant)
    On Error GoTo Error_GoTo
    Dim PauseTime As Variant
    Dim Start As Variant

        PauseTime = NumberOfSeconds
        Start = Timer
        Do While Timer < Start + PauseTime
            DoEvents
        Loop

Exit_GoTo:
       On Error GoTo 0
       Exit Function
Error_GoTo:
       Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description, Erl
      GoTo Exit_GoTo
End Function
```

Open the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) and double click Sheet 1, then paste the above code. Now you'll notice as you change the values within the targeted range `B1:B27` a value with be placed in column `E`. You can change this in the code above by replacing `5` in `Cells(Target.Row, 5).Value` with whatever column you'd like.

Now as the values increase or decrease, the cell will flash to reflect the change.

The `Pause` function was found on [this SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960434/timing-delays-in-vba).

Comment: Instead of `Pause`, can you use `Application.OnTime` to register an alarm to revert to the original cell background color?