# Pausing a programm for less than a second

Tags: vba, excel

Ver easy example: Moving a CommandButton across a UserForm

```
Do Until CommandButton1.Left = 200
    CommandButton1.Left = CommandButton1.Left + 1
    Application.Wait(Now + ("0:00:0.5")) 'Doesn't work this way (requiers Integer)
Loop
```

So the goal I'm trying to achieve a pause that's smaller than a second. I also tried

```
Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 0.5) 'Doesn't work this way (requiers Integer)
```

Is there any other way to pause the Application (preferably for less than a second (let's just say 0.5 seconds))?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Your question looks the same as this one: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602979/how-to-give-a-time-delay-of-less-than-one-second-in-excel-vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602979/how-to-give-a-time-delay-of-less-than-one-second-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the quick answer.