# Excel VBA Ontime function with Milliseconds

Tags: excel, vba, milliseconds

I wrote this code to run a procedure every second using ontime function:

```
Sub startTimer()
 Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "increment"
End Sub

Sub increment()
'some code here
startTimer
End Sub
```

The code works fine, but is there any way to increment by a fraction of a second (ex: 10 ms)
?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to give a time delay of less than one second in excel vba?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602979/how-to-give-a-time-delay-of-less-than-one-second-in-excel-vba)

Comment: The `OnTime`  time schedule has a resolution of 1s, with a minimum of 1s.  So what you are asking is not possible with `OnTime`.  You can achieve it with some API calls.  [See here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
Sub startTimer()
    
    Const MILLISECOND_MULTIPLIER As Double = 0.000000011574;
    
    ' bracket is optional, but kept for clarity
    Application.OnTime (Now + (MILLISECOND_MULTIPLIER * 10)), "increment")
    
End Sub
```

This is inspired by a comment from existing answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602979/how-to-give-a-time-delay-of-less-than-one-second-in-excel-vba).

Answer (score -1):

If working seriously with milliseconds, indeed when subtraction or comparing values, be sure to calculate with *Decimal* and not Double to avoid bit errors:

```
Dim OneMillisecond As Variant

OneMillisecond = CDec(TimeSerial(0, 0, 1) / 1000)
' OneMillisecond = 0.0000000115740740740741 

TenMilliseconds = OneMillisecond * CDec(10)
```

[MS Access Can Handle Millisecond Time Values - Really](https://www.devx.com/dbzone/Article/39046)