# Call a macro 2 sec after a cell is changed

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have macro called 2 seconds after a cell changes.

I am stuck with this code.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"), Macro 
End Sub
```

Comment: It has been answered before, please check the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7549732/2854647

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you should modify your code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Target.Worksheet.Range("B2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.Wait(Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))
        Call Macro
    End If
End Sub
```