# How to change a property after X time in Microsoft Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a very simple form with one field to add records to a DB. After successful record insertion, a success message is displayed. How can I hide the success label after X seconds? `[record_save_success]` is just a static text label. Here's what I'm doing to show the message:

```
Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
  [record_save_success].Visible = True
End Sub
```

Can I add a delay to change the `Visible` property to `False`?

Comment: Timers are difficult and memory hogs. Form has Timer event, controls do not. Maybe just make sure control is not visible with form Current event.

Comment: Using the Form_Current() event is a good idea, however the success message disappears almost instantly after a record is saved since the cursor defaults to the text field.

Comment: I did not say to remove AfterInsert code. It was not an either/or suggestion. Use both. However, what triggers record commitment? Will record stay in view long enough for user to see message?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timing Delays in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6960434/timing-delays-in-vba) Okay, don't need Timer event, use Wait or Sleep or timer loop in Current event. https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/pausing-or-delaying-vba-using-wait-sleep-or-a-loop

Comment: Yes!!! That question was what I was looking for!! The second answer posted on that question was just what I needed!!! thanks!

Comment: On second thought, can probably have timer code in AfterInsert event.